# How can I render a Material UI component without any styles applied to it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to render certain Material UI components in my app but completely disable styling for that specific component. Is there a way to do this? If not does anyone have a good solution for how to custom style a component completely but keep the JS functionality?

I wish there was something like `<RaisedButton noStyling={true}>` that would completely disable inline and injected `<head>` styles but I don't think anything like that exists.

Comment: I don't think it's possible... can't you just create a new component just the way you want?

Comment: The entire point of MUI is the styling.  If you just want a button, you can just make a button...

Comment: I think you can create your own component using the material UI component and add the CSS which you need but simply overriding the default CSS provided by material UI.


let's say creating a new component called "Button"
then just include MUI Raised Component in the "Button" component and override all the styling which you is needed to be customized.